# Is Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 compatible with Sitecore 161221 (8.2 Update-2)?

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 compatible with Sitecore 161221 (8.2 Update-2) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it's not compatible. Please see details about modules compatibility here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/316437

[image]